# Shadow Implementation around a Rectangle

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I am trying to create a shadow around a custom UIButton. But the issue I am facing is that the button title also gets the shadow, which I don't want.
How can I avoid shadow around the button title and have the shadow only around the corners.

The code I have right now is:

```
self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor.redColor CGColor];
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75;
self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
//self.layer.shadowPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(self.bounds, NULL);
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
```

I think it has something to do with shadowPath property, but not completely sure. Right now, it looks like this.

[image]

I also tried using setTitleShadowColor property to nil, but it didn't help.

Comment: One more thing I wish to add :
 This UIButton is a subView of another view. And I am trying to assign shadow to the parent view of the button. Somehow, the shadow specifications are also getting applied to the button, which needs to be prevented

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code. You Can Use Same Code For UIView :-) **Swift 4**

```
btn.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4392156899, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)
    btn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    btn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    btn.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: btn.bounds, cornerRadius: 0)
    btn.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    btn.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
```

Must let me know it works for you or not.